# What is the proper way to "Update complex document" in mongodb with spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using mongodb with spring boot. My question is, "How should I update my documents ?". Should I fetch the whole document and replace it after updating field value or modify just the field value value using some complex queries ?

Answer (score 0):

For more detail, please read the Question ([Can we use spring data repository to update embedded documents in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319790/can-we-use-spring-data-repository-to-update-embedded-documents-in-mongodb))

Summary:
- MongoRepository just do SaveOrUpdate so you need to modify the Collection and trigger Save().
- You can use Mongotemplate to do more things more program