# Can we use spring data repository to update embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Can we use spring data repository to update embedded documents in mongodb

```
    {
    "_id" : 1000,
    "user_id" : "001",
    "events" : [
            {
                    "handled" : 1,
                    "profile" : 10,
                    "data" : "....."
            }
            {
                    "handled" : 1,
                    "profile" : 10,
                    "data" : "....."
            }
            {
                    "handled" : 1,
                    "profile" : 20,
                    "data" : "....."
            }
            ...
       ]
}
```

I want to update the handle to **10** where events.profile is **10**.
I know how  to do it using mongoTemplate but i need to know how to do it using ***mongoRepository***. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to create a Repository with an update-Method? During my resarch in the spring-data reference i couldnt find any hint, that this is supported by spring data.

So in your case you could create a query like 'Collection findByEvents_Profile(Integer id)', iterate over the collection and persist it again by calling the repositories 'saveAll' method.

Comment: Thanks Martin for reply. I know this work around. I asked this question to know if spring data jpa has support for embedded document update. If it does not then i hope it come sometime in future.

Comment: I agree with the answer above. But one more things: If this is embedded documents this mean an object in an object (collection) ~> The problem is same as Update and object with Mongo repository with 1 call.
So Mkyong do have an example (just for work around) - https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/ -
And as the issue raised in Mongorepository Github:
https://github.com/RobThree/MongoRepository/issues/41 

They don't do it here :|